# Do joins using search:search API

Tags: marklogic

How one should do join queries when using search:search API?

I see in [Inside MarkLogic Server](http://developer.marklogic.com/pubs/architecture/Inside%20MarkLogic%20Server.pdf) that one can use a 'Shotgun OR' (scatter query), but it doesn't use 'search:search'. In a [message](http://developer.marklogic.com/pipermail/general/2013-January/012044.html) at 'MarkLogic Dev General' mail list I found that in theory this could be done by  a search constraint, but I couldn't understand how exactly it should work.

My use case is the following:

1. I use [MarkLogic Java client API](https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api) to construct my queries. I want to avoid using xqy extensions if possible.
2. I have two kind of entities (e.g. Books and Authors) and I may want to do queries like: give me the Books published in 1980 that were written by Brazilian Authors. I.e. I want to filter on both entities and join the results, without denormalizing the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct that the Search API does not provide a declarative interface for shotgun OR.

If you're using MarkLogic 9 (especially with the performance enhancements in the latest release), you may find that the Optic API meets your requirements:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/OpticJava

Instead of requiring a shotgun OR, the Java API provides a fluent builder for Optic queries with direct joins between entities.

If you're on an earlier release of MarkLogic or if Optic doesn't fit your requirements for some reason, you can do a shotgun OR query entirely in Java by using a values query to retrieve the names of all Brazilian authors matched by a query in the first request:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_83836

Then, use the retrieved values to construct into a query to retrieve the books written by those authors in a second request:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_70572

That could be as simple as constructing an array of name values and passing the array into a single range query:

http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/StructuredQueryBuilder.html#range-com.marklogic.client.query.StructuredQueryBuilder.RangeIndex-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-com.marklogic.client.query.StructuredQueryBuilder.Operator-java.lang.Object...-

The cost of this Java-based approach to a shotgun OR query consists of two network roundtrips:  one to get the list of names from the server to the Java client and one to get the documents.

For better performance with a shotgun OR, create an XQuery or Server Side JavaScript (SJS) module on the MarkLogic enode that takes the query criteria and executes the shotgun OR query followed by the document query.  You can then execute the enode module with an invoke:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/resourceservices#id_84134

or with a resource service extension:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/resourceservices#id_27702

Hoping that helps,

Comment: the manual shotgun OR query is really not an option. In the real world use case there might have thousands of values being returned. We already have it being done in a xquery extension file and I hoped that I could just use search:search to do something similar. It seems it is not the case, right?

Comment: It is correct that the Search API does not provide a declarative interface for shotgun OR.

Comment: can you please state that in your answer? I think this answers my question. And, please, keep the original info in the answer too, since it is very helpful.